# When is a non-differentiable vector field a gradient field?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields, lipschitz-functions

I have the following question regarding the connection between vector fields and gradient fields.

Assume I have given a vector field
$$\textbf{F} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n.$$
I want to know when there exists
a potential function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \nabla f = \textbf{F}.$$
If $\textbf{F}$ is a smooth the following Theorem holds.

$\textbf{Theorem:}$

Let $\textbf{F} = (f_1, \dots, f_n) \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$. Then $\textbf{F}$ is a gradient field if and only if for all $i, j = 1,\dots, n$
$$ \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_i}.$$

Now my question is, if anybody knows some necessary or sufficient conditions for $\textbf{F}$ to be a gradient field if we replace the $C^1$ condition with a weaker condition like Lipschitz continuity or Hölder continuity (or even plane continuity if this is even possible).

I am thankful for any thoughts or possible references on this topic.

Comment: A continuous vector field $\mathbf{F}:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$ is the gradient of some (necessarily $C^1$) $\varphi:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$, if and only if for every "good" loop $\gamma$, we have $\int_{\gamma}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{l}=\int_{\gamma}\sum_{i=1}^nf_i\,dx^i=0$. It is easy to prove this when "good" means "piecewise $C^1$ loop". It still remains true when we replace it with "boundary of a 2-dimensional rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes".

Comment: @peek-a-boo is there an analogy for gradients of Lipschitz functions?